# An if statment which check access to a specific feature based on specific cases

Tags: javascript

In my React application, I had to add an if statement to check for specific access requirements to a specific feature.
This access is determined by the roles, actions, and features.

I created an if the functionality that covers my scenarios but trying to find a better way to write it.

The scenario I'm covering is as described:

- We have 4 roles as `['study_manager', 'system_admin', 'sponsor_admin', 'sponsor_user'],`
- Those who have access to the feature ANALYTYCS_FEATURE
- The ANALYTICS_FEATURE can be turned on/off from a panel but only if RECRUITMENT_FEATURE is on

Scenario to be covered:

- If we have `RECRUITMENT_FEATURE` *active* but `ANALYTYCS_FEATURE` *not active* only `'study_manager', 'system_admin'` can access it
- If we have both active then `'sponsor_admin', 'sponsor_user']` can also see it
- No active `RECRUITMENT_FEATURE` no one sees it

I was able to cover this scenario by the following if functionality but I believe is very ugly

```
const accessRequirements = checkAccess => {
  if (checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] })) {
    console.log('RECRUITMENT_FEATURE IS ON !!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    if (
      checkAccess({
        roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'],
        actions: ['analytics:show'],
      })
    ) {
      console.log('SHOWING FOR THE ROLES BUT ANALYTICS is OFF');
      return true;
    }
    if (
      checkAccess({
        actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'],
        features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE],
      })
    ) {
      console.log('ANALYTICS_FEATURE IS ON!!!!!!!!!!!!');
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I was trying to change this to something like

```
checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] }) &&
    (checkAccess({
      roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'],
      actions: ['analytics:show'],
    }) ||
      (checkAccess({
        actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'],
      }) &&
        checkAccess({ features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE] })));
```

But this last doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `if` is never ugly

There is nothing wrong with nested if statements. Generally they are easier to understand than complex statement clauses.

If you remove the noise (console logs and split statement lines) from your first working example we get. Assuming that the return is false if end of function is reached.

```
const accessRequirements = checkAccess => {
    if (checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] })) {
        if (checkAccess({roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'], actions: ['analytics:show']})) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkAccess({ actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'], features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE]})) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would recommend that you use the above version as the following can easily get confused if you are not careful with the placement of brackets `(`, `{`, `}`, `)`.

### Removing the statements

You can then reduce that. First the inner statements can be a single statement using logical or `||`

```
const accessRequirements = checkAccess => {
    if (checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] })) {
        if (checkAccess({roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'], actions: ['analytics:show']}) ||
            checkAccess({ actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'], features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE]})) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then link the outer statement using logical and `&&`

```
const accessRequirements = checkAccess => {
    if (checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] }) && (
        checkAccess({roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'], actions: ['analytics:show']}) ||
        checkAccess({ actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'], features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE]})) {
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As the return is a boolean you can just return the result of the statement clause...

```
const accessRequirements = checkAccess => {
    return checkAccess({ features: [RECRUITMENT_FEATURE] }) && (
        checkAccess({roles: ['study_manager', 'system_admin'], actions: ['analytics:show']}) ||
        checkAccess({actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'], features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE]})
    );
}
```

### What was wrong?

What you did wrong in the second example is separate the `checkAccess` call..

You had two calls to `checkAccess`

> ```
> ||
>   (checkAccess({
>     actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'],
>   }) &&
>     checkAccess({ features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE] })))
> ```

But the working example only has one

```
    ||
      checkAccess({
          actions: ['analytics:show', 'analytics.candidates:get'],
          features: [ANALYTICS_FEATURE]
      });
```

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with nested if statements"  Strong disagree.  They can almost always be rewritten without nesting for greater clarity.  In these examples, a guard clause / early return on the negation of the outer `if` would be an improvement.  ["Line of sight"](https://medium.com/@matryer/line-of-sight-in-code-186dd7cdea88) style can be used anywhere, not just in Go.  Highly recommended article.

Comment: @jonah A weak and opinion based article. The author's use of double tabs (8 characters) in the example, me thinks, is a testament to the fragility of his argument.  Nor is there any mention of granularity and the dangers of very high granularity (that the author seams to promote). I could go on...

Comment: Wasn't expecting to convince you... the comment was for the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Also, FYI: tabs are enforced in Go.

Comment: @jonah Fair enough, probably best to direct comments with '@' . However *"Also, FYI: tabs are enforced in Go."*  ??? No! GO does not need or enforce the use of tabs as indentation is not part of the language structural syntax.

Comment: `gofmt` outputs tabs, and the official ["Effective Go"](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go) advice is "We use tabs for indentation and gofmt emits them by default. Use spaces only if you must."  So fine, it is technically possible not to use them.  My point was that dismissing a Go programmer's credibility for using tabs makes no sense.

Comment: @Jonah  My bad, sorry :( I did not notice that the conference (and source of blog material) was *"GoLang UK"*.  Idiomatic JS is 2 chars per indent (This post is tagged JavaScript) so your blog link is a reach for conformation  IMHO :)

Comment: Tbf I did add the caveat "can be used anywhere, not just in Go".  And I've applied it in many languages and like the results.  The idea that nesting, generally, is less desirable than flat is widespread.  Eg, "Flat is better than nested" is item 5 in the zen of python.  I wouldn't have taken issue with your post if you'd said something like "some people hate nesting, but I think it can often be clearer than alternatives."  However, I felt I had to respond to the categorical claim "there is nothing wrong with nested if statements."  :) At minimum you should pause and ask if they're optimal.